# How to change laravel logs format?

Tags: php, laravel, logging, laravel-5

I need change the format of laravel logs to json format like this:

```
{
   "time":"2015-10-06 15:45:36",
   "host":"192.000.000",
   "protocol”:”http, tcp",
   "remote-addrress": "192.000.001",
   "user":"user-logged",
   "level": "warning",
   "message":"exception",
}
```

How to do this?

I try put the next code in bootstrap/app.php but I don't know how to change the json format/object.

```
$app->configureMonologUsing(function ($monolog) use ($app) {
    // Stream handlers
    $logPath = $app->storagePath().'/logs/test.log';
    $logLevel = \Monolog\Logger::DEBUG;

    $logStreamHandler = new \Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler($logPath, $logLevel);

    $formatter = new \Monolog\Formatter\JsonFormatter();
    $logStreamHandler->setFormatter($formatter);
    $monolog->pushHandler($logStreamHandler);
});
```

this is the result:

```
{
   "message":"info",
   "context":[
   ],
   "level":200,
   "level_name":"INFO",
   "channel":"local",
   "datetime":{
      "date":"2016-09-22 10:33:38.318064",
      "timezone_type":3,
      "timezone":"UTC"
   },
   "extra":[

   ]
}
```

Comment: [This one](http://laravel.io/forum/02-09-2014-laraverl-custom-logs) ?

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen no. I need to change the standard output of the logs.

Answer (score 8):

You can specifiy the log formatter in the log channel you use, in `config/logging.php` file.

```php
    'channels' => [
        'single' => [
            'driver' => 'single',
            'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
            'level' => env('LOG_LEVEL', 'debug'),

            // THIS IS THE LINE YOU SHOULD ADD
            'formatter' => Monolog\Formatter\JsonFormatter::class,

        ],

        // Other channels
    ],
```

Comment: This worked for me! Thank you very much! :-) Simple and straightforward!

Answer (score 7):

**bootstrap/app.php**

```
$app->configureMonologUsing(function ($monolog) use ($app) {
    // Stream handlers
    $logPath = $app->storagePath() . '/logs/laravel.log';
    $logLevel = \Monolog\Logger::DEBUG;

    $logStreamHandler = new \Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler($logPath, $logLevel);

    // Formatting
    $formatter = new \App\Components\Log\Formatter\JsonFormatter();
    $logStreamHandler->setFormatter($formatter);
    $monolog->pushHandler($logStreamHandler);
});
```

**app/Components/Log/Formatter/JsonFormatter.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Components\Log\Formatter;

use Monolog\Formatter\JsonFormatter as BaseJsonFormatter;

/**
 * Class JsonFormatter
 *
 * @package App\Components\Log\Formatter
 * @author Miguel Borges <miguelborges@miguelborges.com>
 */
class JsonFormatter extends BaseJsonFormatter
{
    const APPLICATION = 'My application';

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function format(array $record)
    {
        $record = [
            'time' => $record['datetime']->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'application' => self::APPLICATION,
            'host' => request()->server('SERVER_ADDR'),
            'remote-addrress' => request()->server('REMOTE_ADDR'),
            'level' => $record['level_name'],
            'message' => $record['message']
        ];

        if (!empty($record['extra'])) {
            $record['payload']['extra'] = $record['extra'];
        }

        if (!empty($record['context'])) {
            $record['payload']['context'] = $record['context'];
        }

        $json = $this->toJson($this->normalize($record), true) . ($this->appendNewline ? "\n" : '');

        return $json;
    }

}
```

Comment: Mostly your solution has been very helpful, but I've gotten a few headaches from JSON serialization failing silently.